# Php retrieving images through Request vs echo of rows

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Hi I want to ask why is that when I tried to **echo** the source of image from the data base it doest work it gave me some a lot of unknown symblos and when I tried to display with get method through request in php it work.

my question is why does it work through request in php but not in echo through data base fetch _assoc

BTW I used ajax for the method of getting the images from jquery

- **Here** is the wrong one it didnt work for me. The getImageOne is from my
  connect class for database

[image]

```
public function getImageOne(){
    $this->query("SELECT image_posts FROM ratepicture WHERE id = 1");
    return $this->returnOneRow();
}


if($method == 'getImage1')
{
    $getImage1 = $queryUpdate->getImageOne();
    $image1 = $getImage1['image_posts'];
    ?>
    <img src=<?php echo($image1)?> id="imageBoxImg"/>
    <?php
}
```

- **HERE** is the right one it works but I am wondering why

[image]

```
if($method == 'getImage1')
{
    $getImage1 = $queryUpdate->getImageOne();
    $image1 = $getImage1['image_posts'];
    ?>
    <img src=displayImages.php?id=1 id="imageBoxImg"/>
    <?php
}


<?php
 $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'test');

$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$query = "SELECT image_posts FROM ratepicture WHERE id = ".$id."";
$image = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$image = mysqli_fetch_assoc($image);
$image = $image['image_posts'];

echo $image;
?>
```

Comment: is `image_posts` an URL?

Comment: it is a blob within the mysql

Answer (score 0):

The `src` attribute of an `img` tag must be a URL that returns the image data. You can't put the image data directly into the attribute (actually, there's a way to do it by converting it to base64 encoding, but that's gross).

The URL that the `src` tag points to can be either a static image file, or it can point to a script that generates the image data -- it can do it dynamically by calling functions like `imagecreate()`, or it can pull the data out of a database as in your application.

Your second script is an example of this. The HTML

```
    <img src=displayImages.php?id=1 id="imageBoxImg"/>
```

calls the script, which echoes the image data.